# How to find out the full command with which the process was launched?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

The Process Hacker program has the ability to find out the full command with which a particular process was launched (as shown in the screenshot).

Is it possible to learn this command using Python?

OS: Windows 10.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can help you retrive this information once you have relative pid information.

```py
import psutil
psutil.Process(pid=xxx).cmdline()
```